# How to prepare for Oracle SOA Suite 11g Certified Implementation Specialist exam

Tags: oracle11g, soa, weblogic11g

i have a question about the efficient way to prepare for
"Oracle SOA Suite 11g Certified Implementation Specialist" test. I did the course on Oracle University website and now i am looking for off sites resources to learn for a test. Can some one point me to a website that can help me?
I am looking for no cheets or brain-dumps just a best way to be ready for a questions.

With regards

Andrey

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for a braindump.  Doing so in public using an account that (apparently) uses your real name is probably a bad idea-- that's considered cheating and may cause Oracle to revoke any certification you earn.  https://blogs.oracle.com/certification/entry/0477

Comment: i am not looking for a cheet but a question type and subjects in order to prepare in the best way. But tnx for a comment.

Comment: "frequently asked questions in the test" seems to indicate that you're looking for questions that have appeared on the test.  That would only apply to a brain dump.  If you're only looking for legitimate study aids, then your question is only off-topic because you're asking for off-site resources.

Comment: tnx again, i will correct my question.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't count 11g certifications anymore for Company's partner status. Therefore I'd suggest you to prepare yourself for 12c certification.

You can find plenty of resources using any search engine on this topic.

Comment: What does it mean 'Oracle doesn't count 11g certifications anymore for Company's partner status'?